# Gson parser isnt working with doAsync from Anko in specific cases

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, facebook-android-sdk, anko

I am doing an SDK for Android but I am having some problems...

I get the json from the body of the request and try to parse it to the User model but it doesn't work, all the properties stay null, but when I do it without these async and uiThread the parser works. But as I am doing request I can't do it on main thread...

My Android API is 23, my friend tested the same code on API 27 and it worked, I don't know if there is more difference between our devices.

Thanks in advance

```
 @JvmStatic
    fun loginWithFacebook(token: String, listener: RequestListener<User>) {

        doAsync {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            uiThread { listener.onStart() }

            val response = post(body = "$INSTANCE_URL/auth", "{\n" +
                    "\"provider\": \"facebook\",\n" +
                    "\"access_token\": \"" + token + "\"" +
                    "}\n")

            uiThread {
                response?.let { res ->
                    try {

                        System.out.println("BCFLW-SDK \n Response : $res")

                        val user = gson.fromJson(res, User::class.java)

                        System.out.println("BCFLW-SDK Parsed User : $user")
                        listener.onCompleted(result = user)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        System.out.println("BCFLW-SDK Error Exception : ${e.message}")
                        listener.onError(RequestError.PARSE)
                    }

                    return@uiThread
                }

                listener.onError(RequestError.DEFAULT)
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are u not using the `onPostExceute()` method of **Asyntask**

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I am using the doAsync from Anko, that is a layer to the AsyncTask itself

Comment: What error or exception are u getting now?

Comment: I don't get any exception or error, but the object isn't parsed correctly, all the properties are null.